# Idea doesn’t strikethroughs deprecated parameter of an annotation

Tags: intellij-idea, annotations, deprecated

I don’t see any warning from Idea 2018.3 when using a deprecated parameter of an annotation.

For example, in Swagger, the @Api annotation's "description" element is deprecated, but in my code

`@Api(value = "Employee REST controller", description = "REST controller”)`

the "description" is not marked as deprecated.
Is it normal?

p.s. It is only valid for a deprecated parameter of an annotation. In other places (deprecated methods, class fields and so on) @Deprecated works fine.

Comment: Please clarify the version of the dependency? Do you have the following inspecion enabled: Java | Code maturity | Deprecated API usage?

Comment: Yes, the **Java | Code maturity | Deprecated API usage** is enabled. 
The version of springfox-boot-starter is 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not reproduced with the latest verison of the IntelliJ IDEA, please check it:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/

[image]